# Orderby descending does not work with DateTime

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

So I've got this linq-to-sql query:

```
DateTime dtePast = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

Datetime newestDate = (from e in tblExpenses
join rd in tblRepairDetails on e.ExpenseItemID equals rd.ExpenseItemID
orderby (DateTime)e.ExpenseDate descending
select e.ExpenseDate).DefaultIfEmpty(dtePast).First();
```

Without the .First() method, it returns a full list of these 4 dates:

3/18/2013 12:00AM

5/14/2012 12:00AM

2/07/2012 12:00AM

1/10/2012 12:00AM

With the .First() method, however, it returns 1/10/2012 instead of 3/18/2013 as it should.  No matter what I try, the oldest date is returned instead of the newest date.  How do I get the newest date?  I've spent three hours on this and can't figure it out.

==EDIT #1==

Here is the actual code:

```
DateTime dteNewestOccurrance = (from ve in context.tblVehicleExpenses
join rd in context.tblVehicleRepairDetails on ve.ExpenseItemID equals rd.ExpenseItemID
where ve.VehicleID == strVehicleID && rd.ActivityName == a.ActivityID
orderby (DateTime)ve.ExpenseDate descending
select ve.ExpenseDate).DefaultIfEmpty(dtePast).First();
```

Again, this code refuses to return the NEWEST date (3/18/2013).  I have tried ascending, descending, .OrderByDescending(), etc. and it refuses to give the newest date.

==EDIT #2==

Alright, so after some testing, this code DOES work:

```
var varOccurranceList = from ve in context.tblVehicleExpenses
  join rd in context.tblVehicleRepairDetails on ve.ExpenseItemID equals rd.ExpenseItemID
  where ve.VehicleID == strVehicleID && rd.ActivityName == a.ActivityID
  orderby (DateTime)ve.ExpenseDate descending
  select ve.ExpenseDate;

DateTime dteNewestOccurrance = DateTime.Now;
if (varOccurranceList.Count() > 0)
   dteNewestOccurrance = varOccurranceList.First();
else
   dteNewestOccurrance = dtePast;
```

It appears that .DefaultIfEmpty() and/or .First() break the code and result in the unexpected results.  I figure either I don't understand how to correctly use these two Linq methods, or there is something horribly wrong with them.  I am not happy about this.

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL it's generating? Note that the code you've given wouldn't even compile, which suggests it's not your real code. Please post your *real* code - it's possible that the error in your real code isn't shown because you've accidentally removed it when copying...

Comment: Don't add it as a comment - edit it into your question.

Comment: Just curious, why the explicit cast of ve.ExpenseDate in oderby clause?

Comment: milter: the cast was put in to attempt to fix this issue.  The cast was not part of the very first revision of the code.  On a side note, I don't feel that this DateTime cast should be needed.

Comment: I see, btw. what's the result of orderby ascending?

Comment: orderby ascending does what you would expect when the entire result is returned (all 4 dates are returned with the oldest at top of the list).  Doing an orderby ascending with the full query, however, just returns the oldest date and with orderby descending.  On a side note, after doing some further research with some other queries, it seems like .defaultifempty() is causing some unexpected results when it is used in other queries.  It may be the culprit in this problem too.  I am continuing to research.

Comment: Strange somehow. Would be interesting how the linq2sql produced sql queries differ. But as .DefaultIfEmpty() and .First() execute the query immediately, i guess you have to check it either at your dbcontext or db. Anyway, good you figured it out.

Comment: Why would you use a OrderBy and then a First(). This is what Max() is for

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ExpenseDate is nullable, try this:

```
DateTime dteNewestOccurrance = (from ve in context.tblVehicleExpenses
join rd in context.tblVehicleRepairDetails on ve.ExpenseItemID equals rd.ExpenseItemID
where ve.VehicleID == strVehicleID && rd.ActivityName == a.ActivityID
orderby ve.ExpenseDate descending
select ve.ExpenseDate).FirstOrDefault() ?? dtePast;
```

Comment: This gives an error:  "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type System.DateTime"

Comment: That's why I said "assuming ExpenseDate is nullable".